# Android: enviando json e recebendo com php e registrando no banco

Tags: php, android, json

Eu estou com dificuldade para fazer essa comunicação, sendo que eu sou responsável pela parte do php e a parte do android está sendo feita por um amigo(que o código enviando algo), ele disse que está enviando por POST as informações mas não está chegando nada no POST que ele envia, pois quando há o envio eu dou um var_dump e já insiro o var_dump todo no banco para depois mostrar(está servindo para testar) mas mesmo assim nada é inserido.

Android:

```
import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;

/**
 * Created by daniel on 21/09/2016.
 */
public class JSONParser {

    public void sendData(String url) {
        JSONObject jsonobj; // declared locally so that it destroys after serving its purpose
        jsonobj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            // adding some keys
            jsonobj.put("key", "21/09/16-12:20-15654");

            // lets add some headers (nested headers)
            JSONObject header = new JSONObject();
            header.put("devicemodel", android.os.Build.MODEL); // Device model
            header.put("deviceVersion", android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE); // Device OS version
            header.put("language", Locale.getDefault().getISO3Language()); // Language
            jsonobj.put("header", header);
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Now lets begin with the server part
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppostreq = new HttpPost(wurl);
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonobj.toString());
            //se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
            se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
            httppostreq.setEntity(se);
//          httppostreq.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
//          httppostreq.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
//          httppostreq.setHeader("User-Agent", "android");
            HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppostreq);
            HttpEntity resultentity = httpresponse.getEntity();
            if(resultentity != null) {
                InputStream inputstream = resultentity.getContent();
                Header contentencoding = httpresponse.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
                if(contentencoding != null && contentencoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                    inputstream = new GZIPInputStream(inputstream);
                }

                String resultstring = convertStreamToString(inputstream);
                inputstream.close();
                resultstring = resultstring.substring(1,resultstring.length()-1);
                //recvdref.setText(resultstring + "\n\n" + httppostreq.toString().getBytes());
//              JSONObject recvdjson = new JSONObject(resultstring);
//              recvdref.setText(recvdjson.toString(2));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //recvdref.setText("Error Occurred while processing JSON");
            //recvdref.setText(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        try {
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return total.toString();
    }


    public static final String wurl = "http://192.168.3.140/app_com.php";
     }
```

PHP:

```
<?php
static $conn;
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'ProjetoPesquisa');
$cont = var_dump($_POST);

if (isset($_POST) ) {

  $info = $_POST['key'];

  if(isset($info)){

    $query = "INSERT INTO Monitoramento(paciente, info) VALUES(12345678105, '$info')";


    $linha = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    return true;

  }else{

   // $query = "INSERT INTO Monitoramento(paciente, info) VALUES(12345678105, '$info')";
    $query = "INSERT INTO Monitoramento(paciente, info) VALUES(12345678105, '$cont')";
    //$query = "DELETE FROM Monitoramento where info='';";

    $linha = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    var_dump($linha) . "</br>";

    $linha = mysqli_query($conn, "select * FROM Monitoramento");

    while($t = mysqli_fetch_array($linha)){
      echo "</br>" .$t['info'] ."</br>";
    }

    return false;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A primeira vista suponho que o código no servidor esta entrando no `if (isset($_POST) )` , mas está lendo os dados enviados pelo cliente da forma errada. No código Android todos os dados enviados são transformados em string `jsonobj.toString()`. Então não tem como haver a chave 'key' no array post `$_POST['key'];`, ele não conterá nenhum dado, pois não foi enviado no formato variavel1&variavel2&etc. Você deve pegar o conteudo do corpo da requisição (sua string json) e depois converter de json para array. Mais ou menos assim:

```
$info = file_get_contents('php://input');
$arrayinfo = json_decode(info);
```

Você pode usar algum plugin para o navegador que permita testar a sua api de forma mais simples, como por exemplo a extensão restclient.

Há uma pergunta no stackoverflow com mais detalhes sobre como receber json no  [servidor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php)